# json_decode() php manage special characters TM symbol

Tags: php, json

So I have a string let's put `$string = {"name":"Whatever\u2122" }` The thing is that when I use the function `json_decode($string, true)` it replaces the \u2122 as weird characters. I need it to stay like \u2122, I know that json uses utf-8, but is there any way of avoiding this conversion?

By the way, \u2122 corresponds to the symbol of TM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First replace single backslash with double backslash, and then decode json string, like this:

```
$string = str_replace("\\", "\\\\", $string);
var_dump(json_decode($string, true));
```

Output:

```
array (size=1)
  'name' => string 'Whatever\u2122' (length=14)
```

Comment: Why not use single quotes to avoid writing so much backslashes?

Comment: @AlvaroFlañoLarrondo Does single quote make any difference? I didn't test it.

Comment: Using single quotes there is no need to scape each backslash, so yes you can write `$string = str_replace('\', '\\', $string);`

Comment: @AlvaroFlañoLarrondo I tried your method but it's giving me this syntax error, `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '\' `

Comment: Sorry, I was absolutely wrong. I will later remove my comments as they are no usefull and could confuse someone. Again, sory

Comment: @AlvaroFlañoLarrondo No issues. :)