# Unable to parse json file with TM symbol

Tags: php, json

I receive some generated json files and some files would contain the ™ symbol, if the file has that then `json_decode` won't work on it, when I print `$data` NULL will be printed. If I manually remove the symbol then I will see the data.
I am using the below code and it will print out what is in the json file until it gets to the json file that has the ™ symbol

```
$json = file_get_contents($count . '.json');
$data = json_decode($json);
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($data);
echo '</pre>';
```

I have tried using `urlencode` and `urldecode`and `htmlspecialchars` but they don't work either.

Comment: Is $json coded as UTF-8?

Comment: Can you provide an example JSON string that won't decode?

Comment: This question looks like maybe a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34100373/json-decode-php-manage-special-characters-tm-symbol) -- although the answer in the other question doesn't look very good either.

Comment: From what I can see in the files it is 90% English with only the following symbols in the odd file: `é`, `™`, `ï`, `ç`, `í`, `ö`, `à`, `ñ`. I cannot change anything about how I receive the file

Comment: This link may be helpful: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663743/how-to-keep-json-encode-from-dropping-strings-with-invalid-characters]

Answer (score 0):

json_decode will only parse UTF-8 strings. 
If the file you are reading is not UTF-8 format it will fail.

If you do not know the encoding of the file you will be reading,
there are ways to convert the data to UTF-8 before parsing it as shown in this post:

[PHP: Convert any string to UTF-8 without knowing the original character set, or at least try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979567/php-convert-any-string-to-utf-8-without-knowing-the-original-character-set-or)